# Как сместить элемент Navigation Menu

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как элемент меню сместить в самый низ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стандартными средствами сделать это невозможно (конечно, на самом деле, можно, но только ужасными костылями), т.к. меню предполагает, что все элементы идут последовательно и имеют одинаковые правила отображения.

Вам надо при малейшем отходе от стандартных виджетов делать полностью свою разметку. Т.е., например, использовать `RecyclerView` для отображения списка пунктов меню, а выход сделать вне `RecyclerView`, обернув обоих в `LinearLayout`, например, выставив нужные параметры высоты для `RecyclerView` (вес `1` и высоту `0dp`).

Comment: Понял, спасибо) Не буду заморачиваться.

Comment: да и вроде как кнопку выход делать не по фен шую